# Laravel seeding tables in second database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

connection('mysql2') is my (working) second database connection.

When I migrate first, connection('mysql2') is working like expected, the table is created.

```
Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('brands', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    //...
});
```

But when I try to seed tables in my second database:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Brands;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
    * Run the database seeds.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
        $this->call('BrandsTableSeeder');
        $this->command->info("Brands table seeded.");
    }
}

class BrandsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        DB::connection('mysql2')->table('brands')->delete();
        Brands::connection('mysql2')->create(['brand' => 'test']);
    }
}
```

I got:

```
[BadMethodCallException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::connection()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem with your code is you have used `Connection()` method with Eloquent(not DB), Eloquent doesn't have `connection()` method.

You can use `on()` method with model(Eloquent) to specify connection

```
$user = User::on('mysql2')->create(['brand' => 'test']);
```

reference http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage

**or**

instead of writing `on('mysql2')` everywhere

you can write following code in model

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2';
```

and now seed is written as

```
class BrandsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        Brands::truncate();
        Brands::create(['brand' => 'test']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out basic concepts to me. I still am a little stuck in the old fashion programming way...